# Linear regression with a forced zero intercept

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I am using the least squares method below to calculate coefficients for:

```
#Estimate coefficients of linear equation y = a + b*x
    def calc_coefficients(_x, _y):
        x, y = np.mean(_x), np.mean(_y)
        xy = np.mean(_x*_y)
        x2, y2 = np.mean(_x**2), np.mean(_y**2)
        n = len(_x)

        b = (xy - x*y) / (x2 - x**2)
        a = y - b*x
        sig_b = np.sqrt((y2-y**2)/(x2-x**2)-b**2) / np.sqrt(n)
        sig_a = sig_b * np.sqrt(x2 - x**2)

        return a, b, sig_a, sig_b
```

example data:

```
_x= [(0.009412743,0.014965211,0.013263312,0.013529132,0.009989368,0.013932615,0.020849682,0.010953529,0.003608903,0.007220992,0.012750529,0.021608436,0.031742052,0.022482958,0.021137599,0.018703295,0.021633681,0.019866029,0.020260629,0.034433715,0.009241074,0.012027059)]

_y = 0.294158677,0.359935335,0.313484808,0.301917271,0.169190763,0.486254864,0.305846328,0.347077387,0.188928817,0.422194367,0.41157232,0.39281496,0.497935681,0.34763333,0.281712023,0.352045535,0.339958296,0.395932086,0.359905526,0.450004349,0.395200865,0.365162443)]
```

However, I need `a` (y-intercept) to be zero. (`y = bx`). 
I have tried using:

```
np.linalg.lstsq(_x, _y)
```

but I get this error:

```
LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

What is the best method to fit the data for `y = bx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you pass a 1-dimensional array, which should have been a two-dimensional array of shape (n, 1) - so, a matrix with 1 column. You could just do `x.reshape(-1, 1)` but here is a way to do least squares fit with an arbitrary set of degrees of x:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([3, 6, 5, 7, 9, 1])
degrees = [1]       # list of degrees of x to use
matrix = np.stack([x**d for d in degrees], axis=-1)   # stack them like columns
coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix, y)[0]    # lstsq returns some additional info we ignore
print("Coefficients", coeff)
fit = np.dot(matrix, coeff)
print("Fitted curve/line", fit)
```

The matrix you pass to `lstsq` should have columns of the form f(x) where f runs through the terms you allow in the model. So if it's a general linear model, you'll have `x**0` and `x**1`. With zero intercept forced, it's just `x**1`. In general these don't have to be powers of x, either.

Output for degrees = [1], model y = bx

```
Coefficients [ 1.41818182]
Fitted curve/line [ 0.          1.41818182  2.83636364  4.25454545  5.67272727  7.09090909]
```

Output for degrees = [0, 1], model y = a + bx

```
Coefficients [ 5.0952381   0.02857143]
Fitted curve/line [ 5.0952381   5.12380952  5.15238095  5.18095238  5.20952381  5.23809524]
```